# Incorrect processing of last line in c

Tags: c

I have a CSV file:

```
name,birthdate,phone
Bob smith,1111-11-11,222-333-3333
Mary brown,2222-22-22,333-444-4444
Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444
```

I am trying to check if I am parsing the fields correctly and storing them. The following is the code for my function:

```
int loadCSV(char *filename) {
    FILE *x = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (x == NULL)
        exit(1);
    char record[1000];
    char field1[100], field2[100], field3[100];
    fgets(record, 999, x);
    fgets(record, 999, x);
    while (!feof(x)) {
        int rec = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field1[i] = record[rec];
        }

        field1[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field2[i] = record[rec];
        }    
        field2[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ',' && record[rec] != '\n' ; i++, rec++) {
            field3[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field3[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
        fgets(record, 999, x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My desired output is;

```
Bob smith,1111-11-11,222-333-3333

Mary brown,2222-22-22,1-333-444-4444

Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444
```

my actual output is:

```
Bob smith, 1111-11-11, 222-333-3333

Mary brown,2222-22-22,1-333-444-4444

Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444

Billy Bob
```

can someone please explain why the loop goes back to start and why it ends after the first `for` loop, and any suggestions on how to fix it?

minimal reproducible example

```
int loadCSV(char *filename) {
    char record[1000];
    char field1[100], field2[100], field3[100];
    FILE *x = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (x == NULL)
        exit(1);
    
    fgets(record, 999, x);
    fgets(record, 999, x);
    
    while (!feof(x)) {
        int rec = 0;
        int i;
    
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field1[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field1[i] = ‘\0’;
        rec++;
    
        printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
        fgets(record, 999, x);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a minimal reproducible example but I tried to boil it down to its essential. I use the for loop 3 times to copy the fields into `field1`, `field2` and `field3` respectively and at the end I print. I do a read at the end to make go to the next line.

Comment: A couple of things: First please [edit] your question to indent your code, to make it more readable. Secondly, please read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: As for your problem, now seems like a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

Comment: I need to read the fist line because those are just the column names. the second i used the second read to make sure it doesnt repeat the last print statement again. something analogous to printing from the file character by character. I thought it was indented?

Comment: i've also tried while(fgets(record,999,x)!=NULL) but i get the same output

Comment: @BlueApricot no, your code is obviously not [indented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). Also [edit] ans show a [mcve]

Comment: @BlueApricot: I don't think "indented" means what you think it means.

Comment: I indented my code, but i didn't think indenting the desired vs actual output would be necessary.

Comment: @BlueApricot Someone edited your question to improve your code. Please look at how easy it is to read compared to before. This is what is meant by "indenting the code".

Comment: On a different note, if you notice that you do basically the same thing more than once, like the handling of the comma-separated fields, you should create a new function to handle it.

Comment: @BlueApricot Either drop `addRecord(field1, field2, field3);` line of code or post its definition.

Comment: `Int rec = 0;` inside `while()` loop in updated code is suspicious.

Comment: int rec is the index used to traverse the record.  rec = 0 is at the start to make sure we traverse from index zero everytime we get a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't replace any of the suggestions in the comments but...

I've taken your original loadCSV function and created a simple test console app in VS.  I have commented out the addRecord(...) procedure and given the phonebook_length a datatype to get everything to compile.  I've put in a few little comments.

```
int loadCSV(char *filename) {
    int phonebook_length = 0;
    FILE *x = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (x == NULL) exit(1);
    char record[1000];
    char field1[100], field2[100], field3[100];
    int rec = 0;
    fgets(record, 999, x);  //(1) Reads the column listing => name,birthdate,phone
    int linecount = 1;
    fgets(record, 999, x);  //(2) Reads the first line => Bob smith,1111-11-11,222-333-3333
    while (!feof(x)) {
        rec = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field1[i] = record[rec];
        }

        field1[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field2[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field2[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ',' && record[rec] != '\n'; i++, rec++) {
            field3[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field3[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
        //addRecord(field1, field2, field3);
        linecount++;
        fgets(record, 999, x); //(3) Reads the second line => Mary brown,2222-22-22,333-444-4444
                                //(4) Reads the last line => Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444 - AND places the file pointer to the EOF, so
                                // Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444 NEVER gets output.
    }
    fclose(x);
    if (linecount == 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your original function won't output the last line of the CSV and it is read in and then the EOF is checked straight away.

Here is a subtle change to your function that will output what you want:

```
int loadCSV_2(char *filename) {
    int phonebook_length = 0;
    FILE *x = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (x == NULL) exit(1);
    char record[1000];
    char field1[100], field2[100], field3[100];
    int rec = 0;
    fgets(record, 999, x);  //(1) Reads the column listing => name,birthdate,phone
    int linecount = 1;
    while (!feof(x)) {
        rec = 0;
        int i;
        fgets(record, 999, x);  //(2) Reads the first line => Bob smith,1111-11-11,222-333-3333
                                //(3) Reads the second line => Mary brown,2222-22-22,333-444-4444
                                //(4) Reads the third line => Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field1[i] = record[rec];
        }

        field1[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
            field2[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field2[i] = '\0';
        rec++;
        for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ',' && record[rec] != '\n'; i++, rec++) {
            field3[i] = record[rec];
        }
        field3[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
        //addRecord(field1, field2, field3);
        linecount++;        
    }
    fclose(x);
    if (linecount == 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above could be written much nicer, but it will output what you want.  I advise you go away and read the thread about the EOF mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

**Buffer overrun**

Code risk overfilling `field1[]`.  Perhaps not with select input, yet in general.

```
char record[1000];
char field1[100], field2[100], field3[100];
...
for (i = 0; record[rec] != '\0' && i < 999 && record[rec] != ','; i++, rec++) {
  field1[i] = record[rec];
}
```

Expect `i < 999` --> `i < 99`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has several issues that may lead to it not functioning as expected:

Improper Use of feof(): The while(!feof(x)) loop is problematic. The feof() function only returns true after an attempt has been made to read past the end of the file. This means that your loop could execute one extra time, leading to unexpected behavior.

Manual Parsing: The approach to parse the CSV file manually (using the for loops and the rec variable) is error-prone and can easily lead to bugs, especially if a field is missing or if a line does not conform to the expected format.

Buffer Overflows: The size checks in your for loops (i < 999) do not prevent buffer overflows in field1, field2, and field3, since these arrays are only 100 characters long.

Unnecessary fgets() before Loop: You call fgets(record, 999, x) twice before entering the loop, which means the first line (possibly the header of the CSV) is read and then immediately overwritten without being processed.

Missing File Closure: You do not close the file at the end of the function, which can lead to resource leaks.

### My Suggestions :

Replace the while(!feof(x)) loop with while(fgets(record, sizeof(record), x)) for correct file reading.

Consider using strtok() for parsing, as in the second program, to simplify and make the parsing more robust.

Ensure buffer sizes are appropriate for the expected data and avoid potential buffer overflows.

Make sure to close the file at the end of the function.

#### An exemple :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int loadCSV(char *filename) {
    FILE *x = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (x == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    char record[256];
    char *field1;
    char *field2;
    char *field3;

    fgets(record, sizeof(record), x);

    while (fgets(record, 256, x)) {
        field1 = strtok(record, ",");
        field2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        field3 = strtok(NULL, ",");

        printf("%s,%s,%s", field1, field2, field3);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The third field may or may not have a trailing newline depending on the file contents... you can fix this by passing `",\n"` as the separator string to `strtok` and printing a newline after each record.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the playing I've done with it, it looks like you may have a blank line at the end of your input file that you're not dealing with properly.

Let's say the last two lines of your input file are as follows:

```
Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444\n
\n
```

After reading the `Billy Bob` line, `record` looks like this (`?` represents indeterminate characters):

```
Billy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444\n\0??????...
```

After reading the blank line, `record` looks like this:

```
\n\0illy Bob,2001-01-11,222-333-4444\n\0?????...
```

*Your first `for` loop doesn't look for that newline*; it only looks for the terminating 0.  So you write `\n` to `field1`.  **Then you advance `rec` past the terminator and process the rest of `record`**.  On my system this writes `illy Bob` to `field2` and `2001-01-11` to `field3`.  No, that's not the same as your output, but I think the root issue is the same.  If nothing else it's a case you need to account for.

You need to add the newline check for `field1` and `field2`, **and you need to exit the processing as soon as you see it**:

```
for(i=0; record[rec]!='\0' && i<999 && record[rec]!=',' && record[rec] != '\n' ; i++, rec++) {
    field1[i] = record[rec];
}

if ( record[rec] == '\n' ) 
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Bad input record: \"%s\"\n", record );
  exit( 1 );
}
field[i] = 0;
rec++;

// repeat for field2
```

Since you're dealing with a .csv file that should be relatively well-behaved, this isn't a bad opportunity to use one of the `*scanf` functions, specifically `sscanf`.  You can still read the line into `record` using `fgets`, but then you can use `sscanf` to parse the individual fields:

```
while ( fgets( record, sizeof record, x ) )
{
  if ( sscanf( record, "%99[^,]%99[^,]%99[^\n]", field1, field2, field3 ) == 3 )
  {
    // process good input
  }
  else
  {
    // deal with bad input
  }
}
```

The advantage of this method is a) the hard work of separating the fields is handled by `sscanf`, and b) you can go back and examine `record` to see where the problem is and handle it; maybe it's a blank line and can be ignored, maybe it's a corrupted line that invalidates the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is `feof()`: **NEVER** use this function, it does not do what you think it does. Read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

To load the file records, simply use `fgets()` and test the return value: `fgets()` will return `NULL` if you have reached the end of file.

To split and copy the fields, use library functions and compute the lengths properly, but depending on your objectives you do not even need to copy anything.

Also make sure you close the file before returning from the function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// load the CSV file
// return -1 on error otherwise return the number of records loaded
int loadCSV(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    char record[1000];
    // read and discard the labels line
    if (!fgets(record, sizeof record, fp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s is empty\n", filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    // read and display the records
    while (fgets(record, sizeof record, fp)) {
        char *field1 = strtok(record, ",\r\n");
        char *field2 = strtok(NULL, ",\r\n");
        char *field3 = strtok(NULL, ",\r\n");
        if (!field1) field1 = "";
        if (!field2) field2 = "";
        if (!field3) field3 = "";
        printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
        count++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}
```